# Calculus used by Gauss to find Ceres' position?

Tags: astronomy, specific-reference, orbital-motion, observational-astronomy

With very little data, the great mathematician Gauss was able to predict the exact location of where to find the [asteroid Ceres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceres_%28dwarf_planet%29). If possible I would like a reconstruction of his work, from the data that he had at his disposal and the rest of his calculations.

Is the data available somewhere?

Comment: Not sure if this paper gives the data, but from the introduction it seems they go over at least the method. Looks like it might be possible to read it for free too. Mathematics Magazine, 72(2) pp. 83-93. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690592

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Titus-Bode law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titius%E2%80%93Bode_law), astronomers expected to find a planet between Mars and Jupiter. A planetoid (Ceres) was indeed found by Giuseppe Piazzi in 1801, who was able to follow its orbit for 41 days. You can find the original data as published by Piazzi [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ceres-Beobachtung_von_Piazzi.png). The various parameters are, if I'm not mistaken: time, right ascension (in time units), right ascension (in degrees), declination, longitude, latitude, distance (? literally "place") of the Sun, while I'm not quite sure what the last one means.

Gauss then developed a method, which is basically what is described as [Gauss' method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27_method) on Wikipedia. In my understanding, it's essentially an algorithm for refining a guess for the orbit.

You can find a sketch of the story [here](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~cherlin/History/Papers1999/weiss.html#leastsq). A more detailed account of the story and the calculation can be found [here](https://archive.schillerinstitute.com/fid_97-01/982_orbit_ceres.pdf).