# Determine the equation of earth's orbit

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, geometry

I am trying to find the the equation earth's orbit using Kepler's Scheme. After every 1.88 years Mars returns to its initial position in the sky.

> With reference to the diagram and data below find the equation for the orbit of the earth taking average earth-sun distance as 1.

[image]

**Data:**
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Date} & \text{$\phi$ } & \text{$\theta$} \\ \hline
\text{1} & 08.12.2022 & 0° & 180° \\ \hline
\text{2} & 26.10.2024 & 42°41' & 94°47' \\ \hline
\text{3} & 13.09.2026 & 85°22' & 59°23' \\ \hline
\text{4} & 01.08.2028 & 128°03' & 31°51'\\ \hline
\text{5} & 17.06.2030 & 170°44' & 6°6'\\ \hline
\text{6} & 05.05.2032 & 213°25' & 19°\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I am expecting the equation to be of *Polar Form* relative to focus.
i.e. if I have an ellipse with eccentricity $e$, length of semi-major axis as $a$ and angular coordinate as $\psi$, its equation is given as:
$$r(\psi)=\frac{a(1-e^2)}{1+e\cos(\psi)}$$

Using this method , it becomes evident that lenghts $SE_1$, $SE_2$, ... are nothing but $r(\psi)$.

Now we can solve those equations numerically and get the solution. But it is extremely tedious.

I am unable to get hold of any other easy approach.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might help - [Calculus used by Gauss to find Ceres' position?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89380/37364)

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm Presumably, you aren't expected to solve this system totally by hand. But I suppose you should at least compute the partial derivatives manually.

Comment: Are you certain that only a planar solution is expected? (Mars is generally not in the ecliptic plane). Can you assume the Earth's period is 1 year? I suppose you're expected to give the longitude of Earth's perihelion relative to the initial Sun-Earth-Mars direction.

Comment: BTW, the polar ellipse angle parameter (relative to the periapsis direction) is called the [true anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly). It's commonly written using $\nu$ or $\theta$.